# Show that $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{R^m}$ such that $\left| f(x) \right| \le \left| x \right| ^\alpha $ is totally differentiable in $0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be open with $0 \in \Omega$. Let $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{R^m}$ such that $\left| f(x) \right|  \le  \left| x \right| ^\alpha $ for an $\alpha > 1$ and all $x \in \Omega$. Show that f is totally differentiable in $0$.

I had once a similar situation, which contains almost all properties, but just not yet in the multidimensional case:

Let $ \alpha>1 $ be a fixed real number and $ f:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a real function with
$$
|f(x)| \leq|x|^{\alpha} \quad \forall x \in(-1,1) .
$$
Show that $ f $ is differentiable in $ x_{0}=0 $.

We first notice that the premise implies in particular $ |f(0)| \leq|0|^{\alpha}=0 $, i.e. $ f(0)=0 $.

We now consider the difference quotient. For $ x \in(-1,1) $ is
$$
0 \leq\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right|=\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|} \leq \frac{|x|^{\alpha}}{|x|}=|x|^{\alpha-1} .
$$
Since $ \alpha>1 $, it follows that $ \alpha-1>0 $ and hence $ \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0}|x|^{\alpha-1}=0 $.

But then (according to the sandwich lemma)
$$
\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0}\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right|=0 \quad \text { and so } \quad \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=0 .
$$
So $ f $ is differentiable in $ x_{0}=0 $ with derivative $ f^{\prime}(0)=0 $.

I don't know how to generalize this to the multidimensional case now.

I would appreciate any help.

**Edit:** The only definition I know and also given in the script is the following:

DEFINITION 7.6. Let $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} $ be open and $ f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m} $. Then $ f $ is (totally) differentiable in $ x_{0} \in \Omega $ if there is a linear mapping $ A: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m} $ such that for all $ x \in \Omega $
$$
f(x)=f\left(x_{0}\right)+A\left(x-x_{0}\right)+\phi(x),
$$
where $ \phi: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m} $ is a mapping with
$$
\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \frac{\phi(x)}{\left|x-x_{0}\right|}=0 .
$$
In this case, $ A $ is called the total derivative of $ f $ at the point $ x_{0} $.

The equality (7.2) is of course equivalent to
$$
f\left(x_{0}+\xi\right)=f\left(x_{0}\right)+A \xi+\psi(\xi), \quad \lim \limits_{\xi \rightarrow 0} \frac{\psi(\xi)}{|\xi|}=0 .
$$

Comment: what's the definition of totally differentiable? Why doesn't the same proof work?

Comment: Similarly to 1D, $f(0)=0$, and one should guess that the derivative is $0$. Then the definition for total diff at zero reads $f(x)=0+0+\phi(x)$. So just check that you can take $\phi=f$, which is correct for $\alpha>1$.